# Referencing arrays through dictionary of array names in for each loop

Tags: arrays, vba, foreach

In an effort to increase speed, I'm rewriting this macro to use arrays instead of ranges.

It seems passing the dictionary name of each array using Array(key) works for initializing the for each loop, but then referencing the dictionary key as an array does not. I've also tried re-initializing the dictionary key as an array in the same manner as the for each loop.

Is there a better or more efficient way to do this?

```
Sub test2()

Dim arr, arr_1, arr_2, arr_3, arr_4, arr_5, arr_6, arr_7, totalrng As Variant
Dim rowcount, x, rowx As Long

With Sheets("sheet1")
    rowcount = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set arr_1 = .Range("D1:D" & rowcount)
Set arr_2 = .Range("F1:F" & rowcount)
Set arr_3 = .Range("H1:H" & rowcount)
Set arr_4 = .Range("J1:J" & rowcount)
Set arr_5 = .Range("L1:L" & rowcount)
Set arr_6 = .Range("N1:N" & rowcount)
Set arr_7 = .Range("P1:P" & rowcount)

Dim dict As Variant
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    dict.Add Key:="arr_1", Item:=Nothing
    dict.Add Key:="arr_2", Item:=Nothing
    dict.Add Key:="arr_3", Item:=Nothing
    dict.Add Key:="arr_4", Item:=Nothing
    dict.Add Key:="arr_5", Item:=Nothing
    dict.Add Key:="arr_6", Item:=Nothing
    dict.Add Key:="arr_7", Item:=Nothing

For Each Key In dict
Debug.Print findrng
    x = 2
    For Each num In Array(Key)
        arr = Array(Key)
        .Cells(x, 22).Value = arr(1, 1)
        .Cells(x, 23).Value = arr(1, 2)
        x = x + 1
    Next num
Next Key

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: For a start you should remove the quotes, as in `Key:=arr_1`, but not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: And you don't use set to assign an array.

Comment: Btw, arr_2 refers to 3 columns, instead of one column.  And, arr_3 and arr_4 refer to the same column.  Are those ranges defined correctly?  Should it be every other column?

Comment: There are a lot of problems with this code. I suggest you do some reading on the basics of arrays and using dictionaries.

Comment: @SJR Error 5 invalid call returns if I don't use quotes.  I removed Set from assigning the arrays. The problem occurs at                                                
              .Cells(x, 22).Value = arr(1, 1)

Comment: @Domenic Fixed, thanks

Comment: @SJR , I'm comfortable using dictionaries, and arrays in ways other than as ranges, but I will do some reading.   However, that doesn't solve the problem; is it possible to reference the array within the for each loop?

Comment: You can't use an array as a dictionary key.

Comment: Looks more like you want a Collection, if you just want to store a bunch of arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before offering you an alternate solution, here are a few notes regarding your existing code.

**Variable Declaration**

With the following declaration...

```
Dim rowcount, x, rowx As Long
```

...rowcount and x are both being declared as Variant, not Long, and rowx as Long.  To declare all variables as Long, declare them as follows...

```
Dim rowcount as Long, x as Long, rowx as Long
```

**For Each Key In dict/Next**

With each iteration, Key is being assigned a text value (ie. "arr_1"), not an array.  As such, Array(Key) returns a Variant containing a zero-based, one-element array.  So, for example, in the first iteration, the first element would be the text "arr_1".

**For Each num In Array(Key)/Next**

With each iteration, num is assigned an element from Array(Key).  However, since Array(Key) consists of a single element, there will be only one iteration, where num will simply be assigned the text "arr_1".

**arr = Array(Key)**

arr is being assigned a single element array, since Array(Key) returns a single element array.  And so the single item would be retrieved with arr(0).

**Alternate Solution**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set sourceRange = .Range("D1:P" & lastRow)
    End With

    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim colIndex As Long
    With sourceRange
        For colIndex = 1 To .Columns.Count Step 2
            'key is being assigned the column number
            'item is being assigned a two-dimensional (n by 1 column) array
            dict.Add Key:=.Columns(colIndex).Column, item:=.Columns(colIndex).Value
        Next colIndex
    End With

    Dim dictionaryItem As Variant
    Dim currentArray As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    For Each dictionaryItem In dict.items()
        currentArray = dictionaryItem
        For i = LBound(currentArray) To UBound(currentArray)
            Debug.Print currentArray(i, 1)
        Next i
    Next dictionaryItem

End Sub
```